# segueing between view controllers with navigation controller

Tags: ios, ios7, segue, xcode5.0.1

Lets say i have ViewController A with 2 buttons, each is segueing to ViewController B and C
(one button to View B and other to C).From ViewController C I segueing to ViewController D.
All the ViewControllers are with Navigation bar so from view B i can return to A, and from view D i can return to D->C->A.
The problem is when i segueing between view D to B: the segue is performed but now in the navigation bar of B i retuned to view D and i want B will return to A like it should.
what is the solution????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using two ways as far as i know.

1) Use a custom back button on D controller

2) Change the stack of navigationController i.e NSArray of self.navigationController.viewControllers in the class of D controller

**Use Custom back Button**

You can do it as follows in D controller.This is valid only if A controller is the rootViewController of navigationController.If you are keeping track of your A controller than you can use the following also

- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated*

  ```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [super viewDidLoad];
   UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
  }

  -(void)goBack:(id)sender
  {
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  ```

  }

**Change the stack of navigationController**

This is useful if you want to navigate to a particular controller.But the back button still displays after getting back to A controller from B,that you might have to see yourself by making some changes.Don't try to change the navigation stack in prepareForSegue

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    NSMutableSet *controllersToRemove = [NSMutableSet new];
        for (id viewController in controllers) {
            if (![viewController isKindOfClass:[self class]]&&![viewController isKindOfClass:[NRViewController class]]) {
                    [controllersToRemove addObject:viewController];
                }
        }

        for (id controller in controllersToRemove) {
            [controllers removeObject:controller];
        }
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
}
```

**Edited Code for custom back button**

If you want the original back Button

You have to use image for that with code as follow

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0f, 30.0f)];
    UIImage *backImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_normal.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12.0f, 0, 12.0f)];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:backImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

Comment: it's works fine if i wrote the first code in B viewController (in the viewDidLoad) but i want the originaly button of return arrow and not  DONE button

Comment: In that case you have to use image for back button